# Extrude removes material

Tags: extrude

When I try to extrude faces on a pipe it removes material from the base.
[image]

Comment: please give more informations, more screenshots, perhaps share your file... for example does your material have a texture, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I noticed where I failed. I tried to create a pipe by creating cylinder with "nothing" filler and then adding solidify modifier, and I totally forgot to add faces to the inside, and the solidify modifier got confused.